# Loss in a lossless wave equation. Why?

Tags: waves, acoustics, simulations

I have simulated a plane wave in a Finite Element solver. Starting from the general acoustic wave equation $\partial u^2/ \partial t^2 = c^2 \nabla ^2 u$, the weak form is

$a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} (v u^{n+1} + c^2 \Delta t^2 \nabla v \nabla u^{n+1})dx$

$L(v) = \int_{\Omega}(2u^{n} - u^{n-1})vdx$

where $u$ and $v$ are vectors.

The wave source is the left boundary, which oscillates following $u_L(0,y) = sin(10t)$.

The other boundary conditions are Dirichlet ones, $u_D(1,y) = u_D(x,0) = u_D(x,0.5) = 0$, so we have three perfectly reflective walls.

I show a snapshot of the output in the image below. It displays the displacement in the X coordinate and was properly scaled using Paraview.

[image]

My question is:

Given that the general wave equation is assumed to be lossless, why do the amplitudes of this wave diminish as they drive away from the source?

May it be the FEM solver? I am using [FEniCS](https://fenicsproject.org/).

Comment: Is the box an integer number of wavelengths?  If not, check to see if the RHS wall is reflecting waves back that destructively interfere with the incident waves.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I haven't check this as I'd like to change the frequency. At some points the reflected wave is indeed destructive, but as the wave propagates back it will interact constructively too. I did some more tests and I believe the problem is that the time steps were too short. I believe the stability requirement is Dt^2 < Dx^2/c^2, but I haven't check that neither.

Comment: It seems that your problem is implicit, so you don't have stability requirements.